# How to pass the textbox value in jquery autocomplete

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery autocomplete in some textboxes in my web application (.Net 3.5). My problem is the prefix text is always blank. The correct value won't be assigned to it.

```
function TextBoxAutoComplete(scope, controlId, contextKeyId) {

var txtbox = null;
var flagValue;
if (scope) {
    txtbox = $('input[id$="' + controlId + '"]', scope);
} else {
    txtbox = $('input[id$="' + controlId + '"]', document);
}

var contextKeyValue = $('input[id$="' + contextKeyId + '"]', document).val();

$(txtbox).autocomplete("../Handlers/MiscHandler.ashx", {
    minChars: 0,
    extraParams: { prefixText: $(this).val(), count: '10', contextKey: contextKeyValue, flag: 'codePart' },
    selectFirst: false,
    width: 49
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) { // result is a separate function
    var dummy = new Object();
    dummy.value = data[1];
    dummy.text = data[0];
    var test = new Test(dummy);
});
}
```

I call the above method at document ready. Here the problem is I don't get the textbox value (currently typed text) when i pass it to the variable 'prifixText'
    **prefixText: $(this).val()**

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue? Thanks

Comment: out of interest do you get anything if you query $(txtbox).val()? I could be wrong, but I think "this" in that context is the actual autocomplete itself, which will have no selected value

Comment: Worth pointing out that you are NOT using the jQuery UI version of autocomplete here. You should add a link to the plugin you are using as there a several similar versions.

Comment: @mattytommo - Thank you for your quick response. I have tried out the same way but it didn't work.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss - Actually we use a plugin, jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1 (/*
 * jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Jörn Zaefferer
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.autocomplete.js 15 2009-08-22 10:30:27Z joern.zaefferer $
 */) we have added the js file, jquery.autocomplete.js to my web UI project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `search` event, in your example you are in bad scope.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-search

To set option use http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-option

Comment: Appears as if jQuery UI version is not being used here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find out the answer with the help of my friend.

From the handler, "../Handlers/MiscHandler.ashx" I tried to access the textbox text by accessing the value of 'prefixText' as follows.

```
string prefixText = string.Empty;
if (context.Request["prefixText"] != null)
{
prefixText = context.Request["prefixText"].ToString();
}
```

But it didn't work, didn't allow me to get the textbox value. Instead of that I accessed the "q" parameter in the query string, which comes default.

```
if (context.Request["q"] != null)
{
prefixText = context.Request["q"].ToString();
}
```

This worked perfect and there was no issue with the jquery code, issue was how i handled the HTTP request. Thanks.